# How to print a table header and table data only if data is present in qweb reports

Tags: odoo, report, odoo-10, odoo-view

How can I print a table header and table data only if the data is present in `qweb` reports.

If data is not present, table header and data should be empty

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Improved content formatting and added relevant tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `<t t-set="flag" t-value="0">` initialise a flag.
Then check whether any data is present in the table data by using `for loop`.

If any data is present, set the `t-value` of `flag` inside the `for loop` as `1`.
Then print the table header and data only when the `flag's value is 1`

Answer (score 1):

u can use a condition  t-if:

```
<t t-if="condition">
<p>Test</p></t>
```

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html